# SQLSyntaxErrorException when i select a sequence from DB (ORACLE 11g)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, sequence

i have a strange exception only when i try to select a sequence number from my database. If i run this query: `SELECT MYSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL from DUAL` directly in my DB it's work fine and give me the next value. When i run the same query on JAVA i have an `SQLSyntaxErrorException`.

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(MY_SEQ);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
MY_SEQ= private static final String MY_SEQ="SELECT MYSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL from DUAL";
```

I try to execute another query `SELECT ID from ANYTABLE` to try if goes something wrong in my configuration but it run perfectly and return the result.

Any idea of my Exception?

Comment: No, i don't need any `;`. It work's same way with the other query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant select problem. I do `grant select on DB.MYSEQUENCE to MY_USER;`, i have done a grant select but the commit seem's doesn't go ok. And `SQLSyntaxErrorException` was because i have to create a `SYNONYM` for that sequence, without synonym i have to do a `DB.MYSEQUENCE`. So the order to create sequence and than to use that in JAVA is:

1. Create Sequence
2. Create Synonym to use that sequence
3. Make a grant select for that sequence for the user that you have in your jdbc configuration